# django_quill.quill.QuillParseError: Failed to parse value

Tags: html, django, django-models, quill

Getting an error on my local server when testing using django-quill-editior for blogs in my project. I can't find out what the following error means. "django_quill.quill.QuillParseError: Failed to parse value" I do have .html|safe at the end of my codes, and the weird thing is that this is all working in my production version. Any body else experienced this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had same problem. It is because of the old data that recorded before django-quill-editor installed. Just export your data into json and delete db. Recreate database and import your data again.